# symfony2 ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\...\Entity\... could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, tostring

I have encountered something weird:

I created three doctrine entities via `app/console doctrine:generate:entity`:

- Category
- User
- Post

I set up the relationships and everything works fine with the fixtures data (`app/console doctrine:fixtures:load`).

A post belongs to a single category (category_id), and has one author (user_id).

I used `app/console doctrine:generate:crud` to get CRUD operations for all my entities.

When I update a post, I get this strange error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies__CG__...\BlogBundle\Entity\Category could not be converted to string

In order to correctly display the dropdown fields I use in `PostType()`:

```
$builder ....
  ->add('categoryId','entity', array(
     'class' => 'HotelBlogBundle:Category',
     'property'=>'name'
))
->add('userId','entity',array(
     'class'=>'UserBundle:User',
     'property'=>'username'
))
```

Since I specify the `property` option I don't need a `__toString()` in my Entity classes.

If I create a `__toString()` like this (both in Category & User Entities), the error is gone and works:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->getId();
}
```

I am not sure if I do it the right way.

Also, since a `Category` & `User` object is passed to `category_id` and `user_id` fields, Doctrine (or Symfony) should be able to figure out the id column. What am I missing? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: It should work, do you have public getter function for that fields in entity classes?

Comment: Yes, all entity getters are public in both classes.

Comment: From all that you said, I can't see any error.

Comment: Without the `__toString()` it doesn't work. What if I needed the `__toString()` to `return (string) $this->getName();` ? What would I do in that case? How would you handle this?

Comment: You use `categoryId` in `PostType` but the field is named `category_id`. Maybe it's the cause of the problem. I personally prefer to ignore `_id` when naming field since these fields return entities and not `id`. For example `$postType->getCategory()` return a `Category` object and not just an id.

Comment: Interesting observation @n.1. I changed getters and setters to `setCategory_id()` and `getCategory_id()` and got this error: `Neither the property "category_id" nor one of the methods "getCategoryId()", "isCategoryId()", "hasCategoryId()", "__get()" exist and have public access`. I don't think this change is necessary since the ORM annotation is: `@ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer")`

Comment: If you need to transform data from one format to other format you shouldn't use `__toString` method but transformers - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html . However from code which you posted it looks alright. May be if you could publish the whole source code on Github we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just ran into this issue with the mentioned error (and ended up here), I'll post the solution that worked for me - seeing as there are no other answers.

Like the OP, I also created a new table and join using Doctrine.

This error is telling us that the joined `object` cannot be converted to a `string`. We have to either provide a `__toString()` method in the object so it can be converted to a string, or we can specify which field we want to return in our Form Builder using the `property` key.

### Add a `__toString()` method to your object

```
/**
 * (Add this method into your class)
 *
 * @return string String representation of this class
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

### OR add the property key to your form builder

```
// where `name` equals your field name you want returned
$builder->add('category', null, ['property' => 'name'])
```

I simply added the `__toString()` method to my `entity`, I only have the fields `id` and `name` - so the only string representation is the `name`.

Answer (score 4):

In symfony 3, you can't use property.

Here the error message : The option "property" does not exist. ...

It's because the entity field doesn't use the option "property" anymore ([documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)).

You should use the option "choice_label" instead.